# Django Rest Framework: Exception handler not working

Tags: django-rest-framework

The Django Rest Framework exception handler doesn't seem to be working for me. ValidationErrors are getting turned into 500 responses.

When a `ValidationError` is raised, it doesn't get converted into a 400.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/example/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/example/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/example/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/example/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/example/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/example/app/views.py", line 25, in post
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "/example/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 242, in is_valid
    raise ValidationError(self.errors)
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'email': [ErrorDetail(string='Enter a valid email address.', code='invalid')]}
[26/Feb/2020 20:44:54] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 84465
```

In `settings.py` I have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'rest_framework',
]
```

But I get the same behavior whether I have `rest_framework` in my `INSTALLED_APPS` or not.

Adding this to `settings.py` has no effect either:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'bla',
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it depends on the view you're sub-classing while throwing the exception.

I was subclassing `View`, which did not work:

```py
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


class LoginView(views.View):
    def post(self, request):
        raise ValidationError()
```

Switching to using `GenericAPIView` fixed my issue:

```py
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


class LoginView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def post(self, request):
        raise ValidationError()
```